# IMapControlEvents2.OnKeyDown not hit on Alt + key

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, wpf

I want to catch the Alt key plus an addionally hit key in the MapControl's `OnKeyDown`. I did already set MapControl's `KeyIntercept` to `esriKeyIntercept.esriKeyInterceptAlt` but the event handler doesn't get raised on Alt or Alt + key. It does get hit on other keys.
Any suggestions?

```
_mapControl.KeyIntercept = (int)(esriKeyIntercept.esriKeyInterceptAlt);
```

Handler:

```
void _mapControl_OnKeyDown(object sender, IMapControlEvents2_OnKeyDownEvent e)
{
  Trace.WriteLine("hit");
}
```